# Retrive Data using by $or and $and from two MongoDB collectionDa

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

What i am trying to do is display the response from a POST message on to the HTML loaded in my webview. However, the my webview appears blank. I can see the response message by in LogCat by printing it out. However, again my webview appears blank.  Example.html is the page loading in my webview. My implementation is below:

```
  private void startSchedule()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<temPojoData.size();i++)
        {
            tempPojo tem =temPojoData.get(i);
            /////////////////////// Daily and AllDays functionality start here //////////////////
            if(tem.getDaysweekmonth().equals("Daily") )
            {
               if(tem.getDaysbases().equals("AllDays")) {
                   if (findDateBTwoDates(tem.getStartDate(), tem.getEndDate())) {
                       Log.i("Daily Date", "Today Available");
                       layoutID += tem.getLayout();
                   }
               }else if(tem.getDaysbases().equals("Whole Day")){

               }else if(tem.getDaysbases().equals("Morning"))
               {   scheduleStartTimes.add(tem.getStartTime());

               }else if(tem.getDaysbases().equals("After Noon"))
               {   scheduleStartTimes.add(tem.getStartTime());

               }else if(tem.getDaysbases().equals("Evening"))
               {  scheduleStartTimes.add(tem.getStartTime());

               }else if(tem.getDaysbases().equals("Night"))
               {  scheduleStartTimes.add(tem.getStartTime());

               }else if(tem.getDaysbases().equals("Choose Time"))
               {  scheduleStartTimes.add(tem.getStartTime());

               }

            }
            /////////////////////// Weekly and AllDays functionality start here //////////////////
            else if(tem.getDaysweekmonth().equals("weekly") && tem.getDaysbases().equals("AllDays"))
            {
                if(tem.getDaysbases().equals("AllDays")) {

                }
            }
            /////////////////////// Monthly and AllDays functionality start here //////////////////
            else if(tem.getDaysweekmonth().equals("montly") && tem.getDaysbases().equals("AllDays"))
            {

                if(tem.getDaysbases().equals("AllDays")) {

                }
            }

        }
    }

    private void findTimeBTwoTimes(String sTime,String eTime)
    {
        try {
            String string1 = "20:11:13";
            Date time1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(string1);
            Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar1.setTime(time1);

            String string2 = "14:49:00";
            Date time2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(string2);
            Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar2.setTime(time2);
            calendar2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

            String someRandomTime = "01:00:00";
            Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(someRandomTime);
            Calendar calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar3.setTime(d);
            calendar3.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

            Date x = calendar3.getTime();
            if (x.after(calendar1.getTime()) && x.before(calendar2.getTime())) {
                //checkes whether the current time is between 14:49:00 and 20:11:13.
                System.out.println(true);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private boolean findDateBTwoDates(String sDate,String eDate)
    {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            String s = sDate.replace(" AM","");
            String e = eDate.replace(" AM","");
            String oeStartDateStr =sDate.replace("PM","");
            String oeEndDateStr =eDate.replace("PM","");
            Log.i("Start End Date  ",sDate+"------------"+eDate);
           Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Integer year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            Date startDate = sdf.parse(oeStartDateStr);
            Date endDate = sdf.parse(oeEndDateStr);
            Date d = new Date();
            String currDt = sdf.format(d);

            if ((d.after(startDate) && (d.before(endDate))) || (currDt.equals(sdf.format(startDate)) || currDt.equals(sdf.format(endDate)))) {
                System.out.println("Date is between 1st april to 14th nov...");
                return true;
            }
            /*else {
                System.out.println("Date is not between 1st april to 14th nov...");

            }*/
        }catch (Exception e){}

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Does you result collection only contains the result field apart form _id and empid?

Comment: My expectation is get data from two collection with $or and $and condition. My condition is : Name is equal

$or:[{Name:'Name-1'},{Name:'Name-2'}] $and result greater than 300. Filed is not a problem.

Comment: Mongo doesn't have joins. You can't join data from two collections using a query. You will have to do this in the application itself i.e get all employees with(<-name condition->) and then get their ids and do another query on the results collection using (id and result>300) as the finding criteria. If result is the only field apart from _id and empid, why not embed the result collection in the employee collection itself?

Comment: I don't have idea in embed concept. Can u give some idea??? Just can u do write code for this example..

Comment: You will have to let me know about your schema first -  
Does you result collection only contains the result field apart form _id and empid?

Comment: My DB name is dataanalytics and two collections are there in this DB. 1)Employee Collection 2) Result Collection. In result collection result,dob,address fields are there..

Answer (score 0):

I will explain this in a sudo code so that you can come up with a solution.

The first point to your answer is that -> No, you cannot do it in a straightforward manner. The reason behind this is that MongoDB does not have/support joins. Like in SQL where you can join two tables and query them for conditional results; the same is not doable in MongoDB.

But do not lose hope. You cannot do a join on the DB side but you can certainly come up with a solution on the driver/application side. What I would suggest you to do is as follows. (I am using the JAVA driver and Morphia so my solutions' arrangement may look specific to them)

Have a DAO interface for both collections seperately

```
public interface MyDAO1 extends DAO<MyClass1, ObjectId>
{
    public MyClass1 getByName(String name);
}
public interface MyDAO2 extends DAO<MyClass2, ObjectId>
{
    public MyClass2 getByResult(int result);
}
```

First make implementation classes for both the above interfaces. That's pretty simple so I am skipping it to move on to the real part. Have an implementation of the interface

```
public class MyDAOImpl extends BasicDAO<MyClass, ObjectId> implements MyDAO1, MyDAO2
{
    public MyClass1 getByName (String name)
    {
        MyClass1 output= query collection1 with with the Name;
        return output;
    }
    public MyClass2 getByResult (int result)
    {
        MyClass2 output= query collection2 with with the result;
        return output;
    }
    public void getByNameResult (String name, int result)
    {
        MyClass1 output1 = getByName (name);
        MyClass2 output2 = getByResult (result);
        print them in however format you want OR create a string;
    }
}
```

please note:

MyClass1 is the @Entity class for the employee collection

MyClass2 is the @Entity class for the result collection